# Convert csv file to json which has two colums in a row and has multiple lines

Tags: c#

I have a csv file and in one row i have two columns with multiple values .I want to convert that as a list

Example:
 CSV data

```
Id     name      parentid
1       sam         12-george
                    24-jennifer
```

Json Data

[{ id:1, name:sam, parentid:[{ id:12, name:george }, { id:24, name:jennifer }] } ]

Comment: So? What have you tried? Picked out a library for reading CSV data? Picked out a library for creating JSON? Tried to use them? What went wrong?

Comment: Did you try it yourself ? Also the CSV data is not actually CSV I assume ? It would be good to see how the CSV is actually structured.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    const string CSV =
        @"Id     name      parentid
        1       sam         12-george
                            24-jennifer";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csvArray = new JArray();

        // Split to lines
        string[] lines = CSV.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Ignore header line
        JArray currentParentArray = null;
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] items = lines[i].Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (items.Length == 3)
            {
                var line = new JObject();
                csvArray.Add(line);

                line["id"] = int.Parse(items[0]);
                line["name"] = items[1];

                currentParentArray = new JArray();
                line["parentid"] = currentParentArray;

                ParseParentId(items[2], currentParentArray);
            }

            if (items.Length == 1 && currentParentArray != null)
                ParseParentId(items[0], currentParentArray);
        }

        var ser = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();

        string json = csvArray.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ParseParentId(string parentId, JArray parentArray)
    {
        int idx = parentId.IndexOf("-");
        string id = parentId.Substring(0, idx);
        string name = parentId.Substring(1 + idx);

        var obj = new JObject();
        obj["id"] = int.Parse(id);
        obj["name"] = name;

        parentArray.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

This C# source should work.  The array of parentid is remembered between lines and added to if the next line contains only another parentid.

Add a Nuget reference to Newtonsoft.Json to compile.

Comment: Please do not turn Stack Overflow into a code writing service. If the question isn't suitable for this site, please don't answer.